# Change all Anchor href link inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm try to change all html anchor href link using jQuery but it's not work properly. When I click the button it's select the first link and replace everywhere.

```js
var link = $('#content a[href]');

$("button").click(function() {
  var lin = $("#content a").attr('href');
  var rep = "http://example.com/?redirect=";
  $("#content a[href]").attr("href", rep + "" + $("#content a").attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://fb.com">Facebook</a>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="p"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$("#content a").attr('href')` to replace the `href`...It will find the first match and replace to all

You have to use `each()` to find all the links and then use `$(this).attr('href')` to differentiate

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var rep = "http://example.com/?redirect=";
    $("#content a[href]").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("href", rep + "" + $(this).attr('href'));
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://fb.com">Facebook</a>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="p"></div>
```

Comment: @smitexpert No problem...glad to help..:)